# Iterating through multidimensional arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d array in the following format:

```
[[a,b,c], [a], [c,d], [e]]
```

My objective is to identify all sublists of length 1 and compare the element in that sublist to elements of other sublists. If the element exists, remove both elements from the list.

In this case we look for 'a' in the 2d array and eliminate 'a,b,c' and 'a' from the 2d array.

The result should be:

```
[[c,d], [e]]
```

My code is as follows:

```
templist = list1 #list1 is the list containing all elements
for i in templist:
    if (len(i) == 1):
        if(any(i[0] in templist)):
            templist.remove(i)
            templist.remove([sublist for sublist in mylist if i[0] in sublist])
return templist
```

On running this code, I get the error - 'bool' object is not iterable. What I am doing wrong and how I can fix my error?

Comment: You shouldn't modify the list while iterating over it.

Comment: The error message will tell you (and us) the line the error is on

Comment: `any(i[0] in templist)` doesn't make sense. `i[0] in templist` returns a boolean, and then you pass it to `any` which expects an iterable.

Comment: "My objective is to identify all sublists of length 1"-- but `[e]` is also a sublist of length 1?

Comment: Yes I am looking for both [a] and [e].

Comment: @Abc254 So what should your *final* output be for the above example? `['c', 'd']`?

Comment: @PeterWood how do I point to the value stored in i[0] which in this case is 'a'? I was under the impression that any() lets us check if a certain value exists in the matrix

Comment: @Chris_Rands [[c,d], e] will be the final output. [e] is left in the list because there is no other instance of [e] in the other lists. [a] and [a,b,c] are eliminated because of [a]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way how you can achieve this:

**Python 3 solution:**

```
ar = [["a","b","c"], ["a"], ["c","d"], ["e"]]
for pos,inner_ar in enumerate(ar):
    if len(inner_ar)==1:
        for i,inner_ar2 in enumerate(ar):
            if i!=pos and any(c for c in inner_ar2 for c in inner_ar):
                del ar[pos]
                del ar[i]
print(ar)
```

**Output:**

```
[['c', 'd'], ['e']]
```

N.B.: Improvement can be done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will look into where I can make possible improvements to the code.